# "Login" is not successful when querying user table

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

Here's my code. i am trying to create a login page. problem with code is that the 'count' value doesnt increase. 
yes there's enough data in my table.
everytime it goes to else part of the if condition saying invalid login credentials.
my connection establishment happens in a different class so here i just call the object.
what the hell is wrong with it?
Please help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class login : Form
{
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //to show tip on mouseover on text fields
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.username_combobox, "username cannot be more that 20 characters          long");
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.password_txt, "Not more than 10 characters");

        //mysql connection
        Connection con = new Connection();
        MySqlConnection conn = con.GetConnection();

        //filling the combo box with data from project.userdetails.username
        string query = "select username from project.user_details;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        username_combobox.DataSource = dt;
        username_combobox.DisplayMember = "username";
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void forgotpassword_label_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        forgot_password fp = new forgot_password();
        fp.Show();
    }

    private void newuser_linklable_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        newuser nu = new newuser();
        nu.Show();

    }

    private void submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection con = new Connection();
            MySqlConnection conn = con.GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from project.user_details     where username =' " + this.username_combobox.Text + " ' and password = ' " + this.password_txt.Text + " '; ", conn);


            MySqlDataReader myreader;

            myreader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int counter = 1;

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login successfull");
                Dashboard_form db = new Dashboard_form();
                db.Show(); //open dashboard
                Hide();
            }
            else if (counter > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access denied. more than 1 account present");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid login credentials");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        { MessageBox.Show(x.Message); }
    }

    private void username_combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void toolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
}
```

Comment: IN your query text you concatenate strings ( a very bad move ) but doing this you add a space before and after the user name. I bet that this query doesn't return anything (and yes also around the password)

Answer (score 2):

*One* problem is that the select statement is trying to match a username surrounded by spaces, such as `' Jimbox '` or `' Susanblinkz '`. While the extra white-space could simply be trivially removed, take this time to *fix* the broken SQL (and potential injection) and use placeholders, which would also have made the problem more apparent.

```
MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
    @"select * from project.user_details
      where username=@username and password=@password",
    conn);

selectCommand.Parameters
             .Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
             .Value = username_combobox.Text;
selectCommand.Parameters
             .Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
             .Value = password_txt.Text;
```

Disclaimer: I don't use MySqlCommand, so the above might need some modification wrt the SQL text or parameters.

Of course, this entire approach of storing plain-text passwords is hogwash but .. it's late, and I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line,

```
MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from project.user_details     where username =' " + this.username_combobox.Text + " ' and password = ' " + this.password_txt.Text + " '; ", conn);
```

by,

```
var strQuery = "select * from project.user_details where username ='" + this.username_combobox.Text + "' and password = '" + this.password_txt.Text + "'; ";
MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
```

And you should make the habit of debugging the code. 
See what strQuery returns at that point and try executing the query in the sqlserver.
We can simply track the problem.

Comment: problem was you added spaces at the beginning and the end of the username and password. as mentioned by @user2864740.